# Fetch row of data from database based on url variable (ex. template.php?id=1)

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a template that fetches a row of data from a database based on the url variable ?id=1 for example. when http://www.example.com/template.php?id=1 is visited, I'd like to display all of the information from that specific row, E.G the title.

At the moment I have this through looking at php.net and messing around with it somewhat. I've got little idea on how to fix this as I'm new to PHP and don't have that much experience :S.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id,title FROM table WHERE id = urldecode( $_GET['id']        ) ");
if (!$result) {
echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
exit;
}
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);

echo $row[0];
echo $row[1];
```

Hope this isn't too broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, don't run simple string queries, but a secure database layer, e.g. [pdo](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). Secondly, your code is more or less ok. I'd do that like the following:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$query = mysql_query("SELECT id,title FROM table WHERE id = $id");
```

if you put a variable inside "$id" string, its value will be put inside. If you put it inside '$id' string, it won't. Is this what you wanted?

edit:
btw, there's no URL-based thing, there is [query string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string). You get your `id` variable from a query string.

Comment: All sorted, used the code to sort it out along with a missing line to do with the DB details. Thank you :)!

Comment: if you're satisfied, please mark the answer as correct and upvote it ;)

Comment: Have marked as correct, can't upvote at this time sorry :L. In regards to using pdo, how would I go about that? I've tried using pdo::query although I'm pretty sure I'm using it incorrectly as errors appear :S.

Comment: I don't understand. What problems with pdo do you have? I stated, that PDO is better to access database from PHP (in comparison to standard mysql_query). Or if you use framework/orm like doctrine - then you probably won't need raw sql queries at all. Read PDO installation on PHP manual.